# prepend (using |add: ?) to variabe value in django template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have been trying to getting to drips with django, and I am experimenting with the tutorials. So, what I have at the moment is a `View` class which spits out a `queryset` - which I access in the template as follows:

```
<a id="{{i.0}}" .....##whatever goes here
```

which works great. What I would like to do is to prepend the character `x` before the value of {{i.o}} - but I am unsure how to do this. So, I am able to append using:

```
<a id="{{i.0|add:"x"}}" .....##whatever goes here
```

but, how do I prepend?

Any guidance would be great on this.

Answer (score 2):

```
<a id="x{{ i.0 }}" .....##whatever goes here
```

Comment: It's not really to append, it's to [add numbers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#add). It just happens to work on everything that has addition defined, including strings.

Comment: Thanks Pavel for your clarification - accepted your answer now.